# What's the difference between "poppen" and "bumsen"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I came across the second word *bumsen* in a famous movie "Cabaret". Liza Minelli used it there. But then I read on the Internet that *poppen* is more modern or something.

Answer (score 5):

"Poppen" has no official second meaning apart from "to have sex", while "bumsen" originally meant something along "to thump". It became very uncommon to use it that way as an adult, but when I was young (80ies), children would still use it:

> Ich bin gegen die Wand gebumst (=gestoßen).

Needless to say, older children/teens used to laugh about them and it took those innocent children a few years to learn why.

Apart from that, you're right, *bumsen* became uncommon in general. The typical words are *poppen* or *vögeln*, which I deem to be more vulgar.

Comment: Ficken - even more vulgar?

Comment: Ich würde sagen es ist abhängig vom Alter/Jahrgang, der Region und der sozialen Schicht. "Poppen" kenne ich noch vom Stack (EDV), wo man pusht und poppt.

Comment: @SergZ. `ficken` is probably most vulgar. less hard is `vögeln` and `poppen`. its pretty much the same in english: `fuck` and `hump`

Comment: Tabuworte wie dieses sind extrem regionalisiert. "Poppen" ist strikt mittel- und süddeutsch; Hamburg besitzt einen Stadtteil namens "Poppenbüttel", aber nicht einmal Zehnjährige kichern darüber.

Answer (score 5):

### poppen

Im Ruhrgebiet war *poppen* ein Dialekt-Synonym für *stopfen* (z.B. Tabak in eine Pfeife poppen), hatte aber z.B. im Raum Köln schon immer auch die zweite Bedeutung *koitieren*.

Es wird auch diskutiert, ob das englische Wort »to pop«, das lautmalerisch das Geräusch wiedergibt wenn etwas *poppt*, also aufspringt oder aufplatzt (z.B. Popcorn, das davon ja seinen Namen hat), als Ursprung für das deutsche Wort »poppen« angesehen werden kann, allerdings ist diese These sehr umstritten.

In der IT-Welt ist *pop* das Gegenteil von *push* (*push* = Daten auf einem Stapel ablegen, *pop* = Daten von einem Stapel herunternehmen). »*Pop*« weil man dabei an einen Tellerspender in einem SB-Restaurant denk. Nimmt man den obersten Teller herunter, *poppt* der restliche Stapel dank einer eingebauten Feder nach oben. Daher ist es unter Programmierern üblich, von *poppen* zu sprechen, wenn Daten von einem Stapel genommen werden.

### bumsen

*Bumsen* bedeutet: Etwas machen, bei dem durch einen Aufprall oder einen Schlag ein dumpfes Geräusch entsteht. Abgeleitet ist dieses Wort vom *Bums*. Der *Bums* ist sowohl dieses dumpfe Geräusch, als auch der Vorgang (Schlag, Aufprall), der dieses Geräusch verursacht. Auch das Aufstampfen mit den Füßen auf den Fußboden (etwa bei einem Tanz) wird in manchen Gegenden als Bums bezeichnet, weshalb mancherort eine ausgelassene Tanzveranstaltung auch als Bums bezeichnet wird (und das Tanzlokal umgangssprachlich zur *Bumse* oder einem *Bumslokal* macht).

Eng damit verwandt ist das englische *bump*, das als Verb auch die Bedeutung hat *durch einen Aufprall ein dumpfes Geräusch erzeugen*, als Nomen aber nicht den Aufprall bezeichnet, sondern die entstandene Beule.

Da auch beim Koitus Aufpralle stattfinden, die mit dumpfen Geräuschen einhergehen, ist es kein Wunder, dass *bumsen* auch als Synonym für *koitieren* verwendet wird.

### vögeln

Der Begriff »*vögeln*« stammt vom mittelhochdeutschen Wort *vogelen* ab, was sowohl »Vögel fangen« aus auch »die Paarung von Vögeln« bedeutet hat. Im Mittelalter war es für Frauen eines höheren sozialen Ranges Mode, einen Vogel als Haustier zu halten. Sie stellten ihn im Vogelkäfig ans Fenster, um einem Liebhaber zu zeigen, dass die Luft rein war - zum Vögeln.

### ficken

*Ficken* kommt von *figgen*, dieses wiederum von *fuggen*. *Fuggen* bedeutet *einfügen, einpassen*. Das Englische "to fuck" und die deutschen Wörter *fügen*, *einfügen* und *die Fuge* (der Spalt zwischen zwei Werkstücken, nicht aber die musikalische Form) stammen ebenfalls davon ab.

### budern

Dieses Wort ist in Österreich sehr gebräuchlich, soviel ich weiß aber in großen Teilen Deutschlands eher unbekannt. Es kommt von *buttern*, also dem Butterstampfen. Das ist die im Alpenraum traditionelle Art Butter herzustellen. Dabei wird Süßrahm in ein spezielles Fass geleert, es kommt ein Deckel mit Loch darauf, und durch das Loch wird ein hölzerner Stößel so lange auf und ab bewegt, bis der Rahm im Fass zu Butter geworden ist. (Andere Methoden, die im Alpenraum aber wenig verwendet wurden, sind das Schlagen oder Rühren des Rahms.)

Da die Bewegung des Stößels durch das Loch des Fasses sehr an den Geschlechtsverkehr erinnert, war *buttern* auch als Synonym für diesen Vorgang in Gebrauch. Vor allem in Ost-Österreich, und hier vor allem in Wien und Umgebung, werden im Dialekt sehr viele Fortis-Konsonanten durch ihre Lenis-Gegenstücke ersetzt. Auffallend ist z.B. die Aussprache »deebich« für das Wort »Teppich«. Und so wurde aus *buttern* die heute gebräuchliche Variante *budern* (mit langem u gesprochen). *Budern* wird nur noch zur Umschreibung des Koitus verwendet, die Bedeutung »*Butter herstellen*« ist in Vergessenheit geraten.

Da in Österreich (vor allem im Osten) Fortis-Konsonanten in der Umgangssprache und viel stärker im Dialekt generell durch ihre Lenis-Geschwister ersetzt werden, und weil die ursprüngliche Bedeutung des Wortes »budern« vergessen wurde, bestehen Unklarheiten in der Schreibweise dieses Wortes. Es wird häufig mit hartem p geschrieben: »pudern« (also gleich wie *Puder auftragen*). Diese Schreibweise ist zwar häufig anzutreffen, wegen der Herkunft des Wortes aber eigentlich als falsch anzusehen.

Dennoch werden »budern« und »pudern« in Österreich gleich ausgesprochen.

---

Zur Verwendung der Worte kann ich nur die österreichische Sichtweise beitragen:

*Ficken* gilt als derb, wird aber (vermutlich gerade deswegen) häufig verwendet.

*Budern* ist auch ein häufig verwendetes derbes Wort, aber durch seine weichere Aussprache klingt es dennoch freundlicher als *ficken*.

*Bumsen* und noch mehr *vögeln* haben eine zärtlichere Konnotation, allerdings gibt es diesbezüglich sehr große individuelle Auffassungsunterschiede.

*Poppen* klingt für Österreicher unterkühlt und distanziert und wird daher kaum verwendet.

Comment: Das ÖWB lässt _budern_ als Nebenform zwar zu, verweist dort aber lediglich auf _pudern_. "Falsch" sieht für mich anders aus.

Comment: What about "nageln", "pimpern", "bimsen", "bocken", "rammeln", ... ;)

Comment: @Em1: Gefragt waren eigentlich nur *poppen* und *bumsen*. Alles andere war bereits schon eine Zugabe. Ich habe mal versucht, möglichst viele Synonyme für »Geschlechtsverkehr ausüben« zu finden, und kam auf mehr als 60 Begriffe. Allerdings waren "bimsen" und "bocken" ganz sicher nicht darunter, denn die habe ich bislang noch nie gehört.

Comment: @Ingmar: Wann ist etwas richtig, wann falsch? Wenn ein Wort häufig in einer Schreibweise verwendet, die aus diversen Gründen ***eigentlich*** als falsch anzusehen ist, wird diese alternative Schreibweise natürlich irgendwann mit dem Gütesiegel »richtig geschrieben« geschmückt. (Ich denke da an Albtraum und Alptraum, die seit langem schon beide als richtig gelten.) Was ich meinte, war, dass die Herkunft des Wortes nur die Schreibweise mit weichem b belegen kann.

Comment: Naja, darauf wollte ich hinaus, dass die ANtwort ein wenig über's Ziel hinausgeht. Ich habe von "budern" oder "pudern" noch nie was gehört. Klingt ehrlich gesagt aber sehr lustig. Ich stell mir das grad vor: "Ich hab meine Freundin gepudert." Haha... Das ist glaube ich der einzige Grund, warum ich den Begriff nicht bis morgen schon wieder vergessen haben werde.

Comment: Wann etwas "falsch" ist? Ohne mich hier auf philosophische oder etymologische Diskussionen einzulassen, und egal welchen Begriff von "Richtigkeit" man zugrunde legt: eine Schreibweise, die in genau dieser Form im maßgeblichen Wörterbuch zu finden ist, ist wohl nicht (und zwar auch nicht "eigentlich") falsch. Dies umso mehr, als es sich bei der Schreibweise um die verzeichnete Hauptvariante handelt und auch wenn man zugeben muss, dass die präskriptive Autorität eines Wörterbuches zwingend abnimmt, je weiter man sich von der Schriftsprache entfernt.

Comment: Da in der Frage explizit nach den *Unterschieden* gefragt war, könnte in dieser Antwort durchaus erwähnt werden, dass bei der hier genannten Wortherkunft von "poppen" im Sinn von "stopfen" die transitive Verwendung im Sinn von "koitieren" eher nur vom penetrierenden Partner zum penetrierten Partner Sinn ergibt, während "bumsen" in beide Richtungen inhaltlich sinnvoll ist.

Answer (score 1):

Die beiden traditionellen derben Wörter sind ficken und vögeln. Es sind natürlich Tabu-Wörter und Lerner sollten vorsichtig damit umgehen.

Zur Etymologie: DWDS hat ficken nicht erfaßt. Ich meine, es ist die lateinische Kompositaform -ficere von facere machen, im Sinne von Liebe machen/ es machen mit einer Frau. Grimm in DWB meint,  es komme von lat. fricare reiben. Sei es wie es will, ficken war ursprünglich ein normales Wort, das in den sexuellen Vulgärbereich abgerutscht ist und nicht mehr anders verwendet werden kann.

"vögeln" ist meiner Meinung nach nur eine etwas veränderte Variation von ficken. Komischerweise hat DWDS dazu einen Eintrag. Sie sagen, Herkunft ungewiß, vielleicht zu fegen (?).

Bumsen und poppen sind modernere Ersatzformen, die nicht den gar so derb-vulgären Charakter von ficken/vögeln haben. Ob die beiden Verben in ihrem Gebrauch mehr an bestimmte Regionen gebunden sind oder ob der Gebrauch generationsabhängig ist, weiß ich nicht. Das ließe sich wohl nur mit den Methoden des Sprachatlas feststellen. Im Süden ist poppen, glaube ich, nicht so gebräuchlich, es scheint mir norddeutsch zu sein.

Comment: Ich halte das Wort ebenfalls für eher norddeutsch. Als Österreicher muss ich hinzufügen, dass ich _vögeln_ für weniger vulgär halte als _ficken_, nämlich durchaus auf dem Niveau von _bumsen_. Es ist noch gar nicht so lange her (1960er), dass die Südtiroler Freiheitskämpfer (Eigenbezeichnung) als "Bumser", d. h. Knaller, bezeichnet wurden. Als (durchaus vulgäres) Austriacum fällt mir dazu ansonsten noch _pudern_ ein.

Comment: Ja, gut, die ÖR Variante pudern hab ich schon lange nicht mehr gehört, gefällt mir.  Inzwischen hab ich über Wiktionary rausgefunden, dass poppen aus dem Ķölner Raum stammt.